# Creating a button in Orchard CMS

Tags: button, orchardcms

I have downloaded orchard version 1.1.30 and run it using Visual Studio Ultimate 2010. The problem is I do not know how to create a simple button which can redirect the user to a specific url when clicked.

I have searched for days and I have not come across anything that teaches how to create a button in orchard platform.

Hope someone could help me on this part :)

Answer (score 2):

That depends entirely on how you want the button to appear.  If you just want to place a button on a page, you can create a content zone with an HTML widget, then add the button to the HTML and link it to the URL you want it to go to.

Perhaps if you described in more detail what you want to do, it might help.

Comment: I understand that the controller and action must be first created. how do i code the controller?

Comment: I am creating a module. something like events module. I have already created that part. It is smimilar to the Orchard.Blog module. i mean the idea is the same as that. Next i want to create a button widget. So that i can add the button to the event module that i have created. So when the user clicks on the button, it means he is attending the event. so it sends the name of the person to the organiser of the event and sends an email to the person who is attending the event regarding the event details. Basically this is what my button is supposed to do :)

Comment: This does not sound at all like the question you asked.  You asked to add a button that redirects the user to a specific url.  You should ask a different question with all the specifics.

Comment: yea but there has been a change of scope :S